# Integrating $\iint_{R} \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\,dA$ where $R$ is bounded by $y=x,y=2x,x=2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So I'm supposed to set an integral up for both orders of integration and evaluate using the "nicer" of the two

$$\iint_{R} \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \,dA$$ for $R$ bounded by $y=x, y = 2x$, and $x=2$.

So what I have tried to do so far was figuring out the region which I'm integrating over which is

[image]

So this is what my two integrals are:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{y=x}^{y=2x} \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \,dy\, dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x=\frac{y}{2}}^{x=y} \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\, dx\, dy$$

I believe the easier integral would be the second one when you integrate with respect to $dy$ first, because since $y$ would be a constant,  you can factor out $x$ and integrate $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.   I was wondering if my thought process is correct, and if it does can you help me integrate this?

Comment: The integral you present in the title and the first formula is not the same as the two integrals at the end (look at the numerator). Which did you intend?

Comment: If $y$ is in the numerator, then it is easier to integrate first by $dy$. Check the title and content of your question as @rogerl suggested.

Comment: @rogerl I think I fixed it now!

Comment: Are my bounds correct?

Comment: The lower bound on the second integral should be $\frac{1}{2}y$, not $\frac{1}{2}$. I suspect that was a typo. As noted above, integrating first with respect to $y$ is easier (the numerator is close to the derivative of the denominator).

Comment: @rogerl  would the first integral turn out to be $arctan$ if you integrate with respect to $y$ first then?

Comment: No. What substitution did you try?

Comment: Sorry I mean not $arctan$ but natural log.  I haven't tried any substitution method since I don't know how to deal with the $y^2$ in the denominator

Comment: The limits in the second case would be
$$\int_0^2 \int_{y/2}^y + \int_2^4 \int_{y/2}^2.$$
Instead, use
$$\int \frac y {x^2 + y^2} dy = \frac 1 2 \ln (x^2 + y^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer, at least:

Your bounds on the second one are not right; you cover a region which is smaller than intended, namely the one bounded by the lines $y=x$, $y=2x$ and $y=2$ (note $y=2$, not $x=2$).

You need to go all the way up to $y=4$, and take $\int_{x=y/2}^{\min(1,y)}$ in the inner integral instead, and then evaluate this by splitting the outer integral into cases: $\int_{y=0}^2 + \int_{y=2}^4$.

Comment: So... the second integral is not the easier one to integrate over?

Comment: Correct, the first one seems more convenient.

Comment: I got $\ln{(\frac{5}{2})}$ as an answer using the first integral. Does that sound right?

Comment: @DummKorf: Yes.